# Configure installation of dependency package in custom apt-get

Tags: 12.04, apt

We are able to create a custom .deb package called geomonitor-v1.0.1.deb and then configured apt-get repository for it. So that we can install it as `apt-get install geomonitor` .

Now please let us know how we can configure to install a dependency while installing geomonitor. That is in order to work geomonitor application there is a need of package mono-runtime so we need to again run `apt-get install mono-runtime` to install it.

So please let us know while installing `apt-get install geomonitor` it should also install mono-runtime as dependency package. Can anyone please help us to configure it.

Comment: Heads up: the package name should be `geomonitor_1.0.1_<arch>.deb` to conform to Debian packaging standards.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `debian/control` file and add `mono-runtime` to depends field:

```
Depends: mono-runtime
```

Reference: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-control-file